# NGINX rewrite rule to direct path param to query param

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config, wordpress-rest-api, nginx-location

**Context:**
I have a wordpress site on `/var/www/html` which works fine with below nginx rule

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

I have an api sitting in root of my wordpress folder `/var/www/html/api/v3/`

I am unable to curl using below path

`curl --location --request POST 'https://someuri.com/api/v3/index.php/username=test1%2540test.com&password=`

when I try to access this path using uri its works

`curl --location --request POST 'https://someuri.com/api/v3/index.php?username=test1%2540test.com&password=`

What I am trying to achieve is accessing this path

`curl --location --request POST 'https://someuri.com/api/v3/index.php/username=test1%2540test.com&password=`

How can I achieve this by either using rewrite rule (which I am not good at) or proxy

Comment: I’m curious why you want `index.php` to be in the url - is that a typo? Please edit the question to clarify